# Problem of FATAL EXCEPTION: main in Android application when starting execution

Tags: android, xml, program-entry-point

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2

The error tells me that it is a fatal error in the main method but I have a splash and it runs perfect is until it enters the main and stops

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifbBO.png)

This is the XML

```
    < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? >
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android`="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo"
    tools:context="menu.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/lisaid"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoet"
    android:onClick="listar"
    android:text="@string/listar"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.588"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:text="@string/listar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/consultar"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoet"
    android:onClick="consulta"
    android:text="@string/CONSULTA"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lisaid"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.588"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:text="@string/CONSULTA" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/crear"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoet"
    android:onClick="ejecucion"
    android:text="@string/CREAR"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/consultar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.588"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:text="@string/CREAR" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="338dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoet"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/BIENVENIDO"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView10"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="@string/BIENVENIDO" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="322dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoet"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/datos"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/crear"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.627"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:text="@string/datos" />
```

and here is the class

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper conn=new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"bd_usuarios",null,1);
    }


    public void ejecucion (View view)
    {
        Intent miintent= null;
        switch(view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.crear:miintent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ejecucion.class);
            break;
        }
        if (miintent!=null)
        {
            startActivity(miintent);
        }

    }
    public void consulta (View view)
    {
        Intent miintent= null;
        switch(view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.consultar:miintent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,consulta1.class);
                break;
        }
        if (miintent!=null)
        {
            startActivity(miintent);
        }
    }
    public void listar (View view)
    {
        Intent miintent= null;
        switch(view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.lisaid:miintent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, listausuarios.class);

        }
        if (miintent!=null)
        {
            startActivity(miintent);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a SQL database, but it was working well, I do not know what happens.

Comment: Change to this line `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at your XML file, there is obviously a formatting issue in line 2.

Change:

```
 < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? >
```

to

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

And remove the ` in the second line.

Comment: I already made the respective change and it still does not work :(

Comment: You have to learn how to debug. It is the wrong way to ask such easy things on StackOverFlow. You got an error message which clearly states, that there is an issue with the xml file. The next thing to do, would be testing which part of the code is the reason for it. Comment out parts of the code and test it partwise.

Answer (score 0):

Please change these first 2 lines to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
......
```

Comment: I already change it but it still does not enter the main, what else can I do